# Upload .EXE to Web App

Tags: html, asp.net, exe

Sorry if this has already been asked, but I couldn't find a question like this.

Basically, I have a .exe file and I want to turn it into a web app. I want to do this so then an iOS device can run the program. Can I just use an `html <link>` element? Do I have to somehow turn it into a flash game? Do I have to use `ASP.NET`? Or do I have to make it from scratch? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does the `.exe` do? Is it a command-line program? Does it run an in-process web-server? Does it implement ISAPI, NSAPI, or CGI?

Comment: @Dai It's an executable file - it's the windows equivalent of a mac dmg file. It's not a command line program

Comment: An executable file on Windows (`.exe`, `.dll`, `.scr`) is **not** equivalent to a Mac disk image (`.dmg`) file at all. EXE files are COFF/PE files that contain directly executable instructions that are loaded by the host OS' program loader, DMG files are a packed filesystem that are mounted into the filesystem.